# Images not showing in device for Web view in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am working on one application. I stuck with one problem. I have HTML page and some images are in Resource Directory. Whenever i run the application on Simulator it works perfectly fine. But when i run the application on the device the image are not displaying but text is displaying only and instead of image Question mark is showing.

**Code:**
      NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:@"test1" ofType:@"html"];
    NSFileHandle *readHandle = [NSFileHandle   fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];

```
NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: [readHandlereadDataToEndOfFile]encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSURL *baseurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseurl];
```

**HTML Code:**

```
  <img src="mainGrid.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your **HTML** code to (file:// tells that it's local resource):

```
<img src='file://%@'>
```

Then use it in this way:

```
NSString *pathToLocalImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mainGrid" ofType:@"jpg"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWaithFormat:htmlString, pathToLocalImage];
[self.webView content baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: I've checked - it works for me. Try to delete application from device, clear project, check that image is added to project resources, rebuild it and reinstall.